# How to render a dynamic form with Phonegap + jQuery Mobile?

Tags: json, cordova, jquery-mobile, cross-domain

I am developing an iPhone & Android app with Phonegap + jQueryMobile, which receives a JSON with a form previously generated by my ruby on rails web application.

The problem is, the form is too big. It has many fields (with many types of them) and at the moment to load (render) this form in my Phonegap app it takes too much time, even worse sometimes the app breaks.

Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good way to do that. I am storing the html form parts in a database table and then I  am loading each part via AJAX. It's working for my Phonegap app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but you can try to do the following:

- Use the JSON to only retrive the field *data* (not the entire form HTML).
- Generate the entire form through JavaScript and populate the fields using the JSON data. Don't set the entire HTML in one go. Instead insert elements as they are ready using `appendChild`.

This approach will take a bit of time to develop but it might speed up your application.

Comment: Tanzeel Kazi, thanks man but i've already tried to do this way, the problem is too many fields and data form. I got another idea, load only some form parts and when the user scroll to the end of the page I will load more pieces, such as twitter's pagination mode. Anyway, I will try and then I will post here if works or not.